# Convert object to an array and assign its position accordingly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need help to solve the problem below. I have this object that has 4 quarters from Q1 to Q4; however, there is one missing which is Q3. The goal is to convert the object to an array and assign the values to where its index should be. In this case, Q1 should be in 0 index, Q2 is in 1 index, and so on. Q3 is missing so it should be assigned to 0. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
let obj = {Q1: 13, Q2: 5, Q4: 3};
```

// here is the output 
[13, 5, 0, 3]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the properties with [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) and get an array.

```js
const
    convert = ({ Q1 = 0, Q2 = 0, Q3 = 0, Q4 = 0 }) => [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4];

let obj = { Q1: 13, Q2: 5, Q4: 3 },
    result = convert(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```js
let obj = {Q1: 13, Q2: 5, Q4: 3};

console.log (Object.values(Object.assign({Q1:0,Q2:0,Q3:0,Q4:0},obj)))
```

Comment: That works! I can't believe it turns out as a simple solution. Thank you, Mister.

Comment: @dsoumgit thanks, but i think Nina Scholz's solution is better than mine (and will always respect the order of entries, which is not guaranteed with my code)

Comment: Mister, ok i see. Yea, Nina's approach is using a function to extract the values.

Comment: @dsoumgit  ...and returns them in the correct order, which the Object.values method does not always do